# Volume between two surfaces with sum function

Tags: integration, volume

I have two functions in form:

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{i}^{N}A_ig(\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2}) $$

where $A_i, x_i, y_i$ are different known values for both functions. $N$ is number of points. $g(r)$ is a function, usually something like $r^3$ or $r^2 \log(r)$.

I need to calculate area (volume) determined by these two funtions on a limited region.

I should compute this kind of an integral
$$V = \iint \hspace{-5pt} \int_{f_1}^{f_2} \, dz \, dA$$

but I am lost, how to to this efficiently. I thought about using polar coordinates, since I have quadric roots, but I have stucked in $g(r)$.

Comment: Whether to use polar coordinate vs cartesian has as much or more to do with the region of the plane being integrated over as it does with the function being integrated. In this case, if $N = 1$, and the region is circular about $(x_1, y_1)$, then polar coordinates would be useful, but when $N > 1$, then unless you are integrating over all of $\Bbb R^2$, your region can only be circular about one of the points $(x_i, y_i)$. So polar coordinates are not helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express your volume as $V = V_2 - V_1$, where $$V_1 = \sum_i^N A_{1i} \iint g\left(\sqrt{(x-x_{1i})^2 + (y-y_{1i})^2}\right)dxdy$$ and
$$V_2 = \sum_i^N A_{2i} \iint g\left(\sqrt{(x-x_{2i})^2 + (y-y_{2i})^2}\right)dxdy$$
where $f_1(x,y) = \sum_i^N A_{1i} g\left(\sqrt{(x-x_{1i})^2 + (y-y_{1i})^2}\right)$ and $f_2(x,y) = \sum_i^N A_{2i} g\left(\sqrt{(x-x_{2i})^2 + (y-y_{2i})^2}\right)$.

So if you can determine the function $$h(u,v) = \iint g\left(\sqrt{(x-u)^2 + (y-v)^2}\right)dxdy$$ you can use that function to calculate
$$V = \sum_i^N \left(A_{2i}h(x_{2i},y_{2i}) - A_{1i}h(x_{1i},y_{1i})\right)$$